# How can I get a Google Document's Description?

Tags: c#, google-data-api, google-drive-api

## The Goal

Say I have a collection/folder of documents in Google Docs/Drive, and I want to programmatically retrieve the Description associated with each:

(You get this by selecting the file in the list, then hitting the "eye" icon)

[image: The description I want]

## The <strike>Working</strike> Code

I am using the [.NET library for the Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) and have the basic login and retrieval working without issue:

```cs
GDataCredentials credentials = BuildSomethingUp();
RequestSettings settings 
    = new RequestSettings("code.google.com/p/exult/", credentials);
Request request = new Request(settings);
Feed<Document> feed = request.GetFolderContent(resourceId);                     
List<Document> documents = feed.Entries.ToList();

foreach (Document document in documents
    .Where(item => item.Type != Document.DocumentType.Folder))
{
   string summary = document.Summary; //y no can haz?
}
```

However, the `.Summary` property always comes back as null.

## The Question(s)

1. I was working on the assumption that `.Summary` was the correct location based on some deprecated code sections, etc. Is this a bogus assumption?
2. How else might I retrieve the description associated with the document? ("I can haz dezcryption?" in the ludicrous example above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET client library didn't expose that field, I just committed some code in rev. 1189 (http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/detail?r=1189) that adds a Description property to the DocumentEntry class.
You can now access the description with the following code:

```
string description = document.DocumentEntry.Description;
```