# Google DocumentsList API - programmatically setting the Description

Tags: .net, google-docs-api, google-data-api

## Background

I am currently implementing an application with Google Drive/Docs. Using the latest [.NET library for Google Data APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) library I am uploading images, leveraging Google Drive as an image library.

## Problem

I would like to be able to set the Description field associated with each item in Google Drive. The uploads work correctly, I can't get the Description field to work.

I can see the modification mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567582/how-can-i-get-a-google-documents-description) has been integrated into the latest library so the `DocumentEntry` class now has a `Description` member.

When setting this new member to the text I want a `(400) Bad Request` error is thrown when Inserting the file in Google Drive. The full error is:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>ParseException</code>
        <internalReason>[Line 3, Column 42, element docs:description] Unknown attribute: 'value' </internalReason>
    </error>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>ParseException</code>
        <internalReason>Unknown attribute: 'value' </internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

I have tried using `.Summary` as well as `.Content.Content` but with no result. Code as an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
 DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();

 entry.Title.Text = "Test Upload";
 entry.Description = "Tag1, Tag2"; // Once I set this I get the error
 entry.Summary.Text = "Tag3, Tag 4"; // This doesn't do anything!
```

## Question

Any assistance on experience people have doing this or looking into it before would be appreciated.

Has anyone successfully implemented this feature? Or, is a limitation of the Google API that can't be controlled by the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docs:description` element no longer accepts its value as an attribute:

```
<docs:description value="Tag1 Tag2" />
```

Instead, the value must be passed as the content of the element:

```
<docs:description>Tag1, Tag2</docs:description>
```

The .NET library has been fixed as of rev. 1196:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/detail?r=1196

Please checkout the latest source and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much Claudio. I have checked out the latest library source, compiled and that is now all working as expected.